# Is There SSIS Merge Component Equivalent in Talend?

Tags: talend

I am new to Talend, and I was wondering if there is a component in Talend that does what SSIS Merge Component does. Basically I have multiple files which has the same structure to be merged into one file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure! This component is tUnite.
Just connect your input files to tUnite then connect it to the next component.
[image]

Hop this helps.
TRF